# R get number and length of stay from time variable

Tags: r

I am interested in finding the number and length of stay of every inpatient in a hospital. The difficulty is that patients can be in the hospital several times a year (with break) as inpatients or not, like patient 16 in the example.

Here is a minimal example of my data:

```
PID              Time Inpatient
1 14-01-12 21:37:00         1
1 14-01-12 21:40:00         1
1 14-01-13 07:23:00         1
1 14-01-13 07:23:00         1
2 14-01-27 12:36:00         0
3 14-02-11 10:06:00         0
3 14-08-04 12:43:00         0
16 14-10-14 17:16:00         1
16 14-10-15 06:41:00         1
16 14-10-15 11:15:00         1
16 14-10-16 17:51:00         1
16 14-10-16 18:47:00         1
16 14-10-17 11:22:00         1
16 14-10-17 18:41:00         1
16 14-10-18 11:40:00         1
16 14-12-18 08:57:00         1
16 14-12-18 09:10:00         1
16 14-12-18 12:43:00         1
```

or:

```
PID <- c(rep(1, 4), 2, 3, 3, rep(16, 11))
Time <- c("14-01-12 21:37:00 LMT", "14-01-12 21:40:00 LMT", "14-01-13 07:23:00 LMT",
          "14-01-13 07:23:00 LMT", "14-01-27 12:36:00 LMT", "14-02-11 10:06:00 LMT",
          "14-08-04 12:43:00 LMT", "14-10-14 17:16:00 LMT", "14-10-15 06:41:00 LMT", 
          "14-10-15 11:15:00 LMT", "14-10-16 17:51:00 LMT", "14-10-16 18:47:00 LMT",
          "14-10-17 11:22:00 LMT", "14-10-17 18:41:00 LMT", "14-10-18 11:40:00 LMT",
          "14-12-18 08:57:00 LMT", "14-12-18 09:10:00 LMT", "14-12-18 12:43:00 LMT")
Inpatient <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(0, 3), rep(1, 11))
df <- data.frame(PID = PID, Time = Time, Inpatient = Inpatient)
```

What I want is a column that could look like that:

```
df$Stay <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(0, 3), rep(1, 8), rep(2, 3))
```

From this column I then want to calculate the duration of each stay.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You just need a rule to determine when someone checked in and out. How do you know the last 3 rows are a new visit? If your answer is that it is a few months from the last time, that isn't good enough. What if someone checked out one day and checked back in the next day. That would be a new visit but the dates will look like it was continuous.

Comment: Hopefully your medical records system has an Admissuons, Discharges, and Transfers log (AT log) that will record every event as well as its type. Merging that log with your current data should give you what you need to solve this. But you'll also need the unique admission ID